# Magento - Duplicate entry when importing backup

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, import, backup

I have some serious problems with an sql backup of a shop which I only have in form of a sql backup.
Every time I want to import the backup with phpmyadmin (even on a new database), I get this error:

> INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_datetime` VALUES
>   (1,3,52,0,3,NULL),(2,3,53,0,3,NULL),(9,3,52,0,7,NULL),(10,3,53,0,7,NULL),(11,3,52,0,8,NULL),(12,3,53,0,8,NULL),(13,3,52,0,9,NULL),(14,3,53,0,9,NULL),(15,3,52,0,10,NULL),(16,3,53,0,10,NULL),(25,3,52,0,15,NULL),(26,3,53,0,15,NULL),(33,3,52,0,19,NULL),(34,3,53,0,19,NULL),(35,3,52,0,20,NULL),(36,3,53,0,20,NULL),(37,3,52,0,21,NULL),(38,3,53,0,21,NULL),(203,3,52,0,104,NULL),(204,3,53,0,104,NULL),(207,3,52,0,106,NULL),(208,3,53,0,106,NULL),(209,3,52,0,107,NULL),(210,3,53,0,107,NULL),(211,3,52,0,108,NULL),(212,3,53,0,108,NULL),(213,3,52,0,109,NULL),(214,3,53,0,109,NULL),(215,3,52,0,110,NULL),(216,3,53,0,110,NULL),(217,3,52,0,111,NULL),(218,3,53,0,111,NULL),(219,3,52,0,112,NULL),(220,3,53,0,112,NULL),(221,3,52,0,113,NULL),(222,3,53,0,113,NULL),(223,3,52,0,114,NULL),(224,3,53,0,114,NULL),(225,3,52,0,115,NULL),(226,3,53,0,115,NULL),(227,3,52,0,116,NULL),(228,3,53,0,116,NULL),(229,3,52,0,117,NULL),(230,3,53,0,117,NULL),(231,3,52,0,118,N[...]
>
> MySQL responds:
>
> #1062 - Duplicate entry '3-249-52-0' for key 'B3A14FF699AA1FA4D4DDA0B048582A7A'

There are several thousand products and almost a hundred of categories I need from that file! I tried disableling the foreign key checks, but nothing seems to work. I also just took the tables with the prefixes "category_" and "eav_" and put it in a seperate sql file, but the same there.... (I also could not find " 3-249-52-0 " or the key in the sql file)

Anyone got an idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: try increasing your "max_allowed_packet" to higher value say 1024MB. You can do so by changing variable "max_allowed_packet" in my.ini(in Windows found generally in MySQL installation directory)or my.cnf(in linux found generally at "/etc/my.cnf") and restart the MySQL server. Hope it will help you.

Comment: http://www.slicewise.net/index.php?id=82 I found this don't don't know how to use it with my problem

Comment: Here is one example for the not working tables:  http://justpaste.it/177n

Answer (score 0):

I understand it is an old thread however, I had some success by looking at raw sql file in a text editor.

Here I found that some of my rows where indeed duplicated and I was able to remove the duplicates by hand. Luckily for me there where only five or six duplicate lines.

It might be a good place to start debugging.